# Showing keyboard via keyboardFrameWillChange causes table data to scroll out of view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, keyboard

Been struggling for about 3 days getting an implementation of a scrollable keyboard working.  Here's what I have:

UIViewController with the following hierarchy:

[image]

The above diagram shows that I have a messaging style UITableView + "dockable" UIView with a textview and send button embedded in View->ScrollView->ContentView.

In viewWillAppear:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardFrameDidChange:) name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
```

And keyboardFrameWillChange implemented:

```
- (void)keyboardFrameWillChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    CGRect endFrame =  [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    NSTimeInterval duration = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    UIViewAnimationCurve curve = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] unsignedIntegerValue];
    UIViewAnimationOptions options = (curve << 16) | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState;

    CGRect newFrame = self.view.frame;
    newFrame.origin.y = endFrame.origin.y - newFrame.size.height;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:options animations:^{
        self.view.frame = newFrame;
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Which gives me an almost completely functional show and hide of the keyboard just from using keyboardFrameWillChange. This includes setting Keyboard drag dismissal on the storyboard.

I'm having one issue though: the entire view (whatever view that is) is being shifted, so if there are only a few items in the tableview, my code scrolls the top part of the view out of the way so I can no longer see them.

I have tried resizing the tableview since what I *believe* is happening is the scrollview is scrolling the full sized tableview out of the way instead of the tableview being resized.  I have a strong feeling I'm getting my views confused, but my efforts to fix this have been in vain.

FYI there are no autolayout issues and everything is attached to the proper views and such (i.e. UIView is docked below tableview and to the bottom of the parent scrollview.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is interested, I solved my own question.

In keyboardFrameDidChange, I was shifting the entire tableview up to accommodate the keyboard, which was causing rows to appear off screen.  What I was missing was changing the contentInsets to "resize" the tableview to fill the remaining space on the screen.

The insets became top adjusted for keyboard height and bottom adjusted for the toolbar.  toolBar is the view anchored to the bottom below the tableview.

In viewWillAppear:

```
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeShown:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardFrameWillChange:) name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
```

In viewWillDisappear:

```
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Implementation of keyboardWillBeShown:

```
NSLog(@"Keyboard will be shown");

CGRect keyboardFrame = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(keyboardFrame.size.height, 0.0, toolBar.bounds.size.height, 0.0);

tableView.contentInset = contentInsets;
tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
```

Implementation of keyboardWillBeHidden:

```
NSLog(@"Keyboard will be hidden");

tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
```

Implementation of keyboardFrameWillChange:

```
NSLog(@"Keyboard frame will change");

NSTimeInterval duration = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
UIViewAnimationCurve curve = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] unsignedIntegerValue];
UIViewAnimationOptions options = (curve << 16) | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState;

CGRect keyboardFrame =  [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
CGRect contentFrame = self.view.frame;
contentFrame.origin.y = keyboardFrame.origin.y - contentFrame.size.height;

[UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:options animations:^{
    self.view.frame = contentFrame;
} completion:nil];
```

Thanks to Douglas Hill for pointing me in the general direction.

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions that might help:

Don’t change both `frame` and `contentInset`; changing just one should be sufficient and easier to manage. I recommend only changing `contentInset`.

One of `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` or `UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification` should tell you everything you need; you can deal with the keyboard in one method. The frame will go offscreen when the keyboard hides.

When you undo your changes to `contentInset`, put this property back to how you found it. `UIViewController` will [automatically adjust scroll view insets](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets) to avoid the status bar, navigation bar, and toolbar or tab bar. This might be the cause of your first problem.

I know libraries are junk, but you might want to check out my [DHAvoidKeyboardBehaviour](https://github.com/douglashill/DHAvoidKeyboardBehaviour). At least it’s only 34 lines of junk.

---

Also: you are registering for `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` but your method is called `keyboardFrameDidChange:`. Being sloppy about the distinction between *will* and *did* will bite you one day.

Comment: By "junk" I meant that a lot of them have memory leaks or do a lot of unnecessary stuff. Yours doesn't look like it does, which is good. I took a look at your project and tried to modify for my use, but my content doesn't scroll with the keyboard. I tied the scrollview calls to the IBOutlet scrollView in my ViewController (see diagram in original post). Thank you for catching the WillChange/DidChange bug. That was definitely a mistake.

Comment: So you have a scroll view inside another scroll view, which complicates things (`UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`). I don't know exactly what behaviour you want, but maybe the scroll view to avoid the keyboard is the table view, and it also needs to update its `contentInset` when the containing scroll scrolls.